# Magento 2 location of content in getChildHtml()

Tags: magento2, newsletter, locations, customer-registration

I want to know the file location of

```
customer.form.register.newsletter`' in `$block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter');
```

I find it difficult to find out the location or files related to it.

Comment: anywhere code will have coment. <br>ex: 
`/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
`

Answer (score 2):

you can not find any files related to it because now this section unused, this section allow yourself or developer to add new content or block to this position.

To add new block to this section you can create new xml file name `customer_account_create.xml` :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer.form.register.newsletter">
            <block class="Your_Block_Name" name="name_of_this_block" template="Vendor_Module::file_name.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also available a way how to get to know a template location.

These are **template path hints**.

A page with enabled template path hints will look like:
[image]

Template path hints can be enabled/disabled in Magento backend:

> Stores->Settings->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug section